# Fabrication gem: how to pass custom values to init_with()?

Tags: ruby, fabrication-gem

The [Fabrication gem](https://github.com/paulelliott/fabrication) allows us to pass custom arguments to the constructor of the class we are fabricating:

```
on_init { init_with('something', true) }
```

But how can I pass custom values for `init_with` in object generation time?

For the object fields, I can do like the following, but is there a way to pass the values to `init_with`?

```
Fabricate(:foobar, attr1: 'something', attr2: true)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, this is not possible.

```
  def build_instance_with_init_callback(callback)
    self._instance = _klass.new(*callback.call)
    set_attributes
  end
```

You are stuck with what you used in the fabricator definition.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the block syntax at Fabricate time just like you would when you define the Fabricator.

```
Fabricate(:foobar, attr1: 'something', attr2: true) do
  on_init { init_with('another', 'thing') }
end
```

Comment: Thanks Paul, but unfortunately the class I'm using has a lot of constructor parameters and I'd like to keep them all on the fabricator definition and only change 1 or 2 in the fabricate time... is there a way to do that?